# How I can use different objects in ViewController to be fullscreen in every iPhone and iPad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller

I have a project on Objective C. It has many textfields,buttons,search buttons so it runs cool on iPhone 6, iPhone 6 plus, but on others some objects disappear. Also I make LaunchImage to every iPhone and iPad which I use, but it doesn't help. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Every object position is relative to their parent.

So, you need to use autolayout to adjust your elements in different resolutions.

You can check Apple's guide about it:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Also this useful tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1